# How can I overwrite the entire document, instead of just updating the fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I overwrite the entire document, instead of just updating the fields?
Here is the method I use right now but doesn't work:

```
updateFilmTitle: function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    filmTitleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {
        overwrite: true
    }, {
        new: true
    }, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json(error);
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
        console.log("filmTitle form has been updated!");
        res.json(response);
        console.log(response);
    });
},
```

here how my model looks like,

```
var venueSchema = new Schema({    
    ticketServiceRequired: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    filmSettings: {
        type: {
            filmContactName: { type: String, required: true },
            filmSeatingAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
            filmMediaDelivery: { type: Array, required: true },
            filmRentalFee: {
                price: { type: Number, required: true },
                type: { type: String, required: true },
            },
        }
    },

 });
```

Comment: Simply not using modifiers such as `$set` has always performed this behavior. `findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,{ new: true},(err,response) => {`. But it's generally not good practice to "replace" unless you know you really mean it. It's not atomic and therefore does not account for other operations that "could" be also modifying the document. This is why we say to use `$set` on "individual fields". There is a `.replaceOne()` which "does not allow" modifiers, specifically for when you intend such a purpose, but this does not return the modified document.

Comment: findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,{ new: true},(err,response) => {.
This dint overwrite the document :(

Comment: It does for the rest of us. You have other problems though as I have indicated on other questions you have asked.

Comment: what are the other problems?  I dont see anything on the other question. I have added my model in the question. Please check.

Comment: @NeilLunn Mongoose implicitly uses `$set` for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` and `overwrite` both are options, so it should be this:

```
filmTitleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {
  overwrite : true,
  new       : true
}, (error, response) => { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks robert. God bless you.